# iOS 11 Twitter Integration Client-side workaround

Tags: ios, twitter, ios11

iOS 11 seems to have gotten rid of the usual client-side integration for Twitter... what's the right way to integrate social media for iOS 11?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter offers [Twitter Kit](http://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/overview) which is an SDK for iOS and Android that provides authentication using the Twitter app (if installed) or website. That's the replacement for the previous built-in iOS integration.

Comment: They don't support posting gif through their SDK - unity plugin